# fxgl over 11.3 and missing gluon

Tags: javafx, fxgl

I try to use fxgl engine with java 11.

With release 11.4 and over

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.almasb:fxgl:11.4'
}
```

I get this error

> Could not find com.gluonhq.attach:storage:4.0.2

Comment: Are you trying to build a mobile application? This missing part is from the Gluon Mobile framework.

Comment: no, only try to build a basic example. https://github.com/AlmasB/FXGL11-Gradle  with 11.3 it's ok.

Comment: thanks for raising this, now fixed at: https://github.com/AlmasB/FXGL11-Gradle If further issues, feel free to raise them on GitHub directly